# what's this op-amp Oscillator frequency?

Tags: oscillator

I am trying to calculate the oscillation frequency of this op-amp.
Please point out where I am wrong.

[image: op-amp]

It's easy to get the Gain in s-domain.

$$G(s) = - \frac{Z_F} {R}$$

Now we will replace \$Z_F\$ with  a resonant
circuit.

[image: ZF]

$$Z_F = \frac{(sL + r) \frac{1} {sC}} {(sL + r) + \frac{1} {sC}} = \frac{sL + r} {s^2LC + srC + 1}$$

Gain will be
$$G(s) = -\frac{sL + r} {R(s^2LC + srC + 1)}$$

In frequency domain
$$G(w) = -\frac{j \omega L + r} {R(- \omega^2 LC + j \omega rC + 1)}$$
$$ \Longrightarrow  G(w)= -\frac{r + j(\omega L - \omega^3 L^2 C - \omega r^2 C)} {R \Bigr[ (1- \omega^2 L C )^2 + \omega^2 r^2 C^2\Bigr]}
$$

In order to oscillate, the imaginary should be zero.
$$ (\omega L - \omega^3 L^2 C - \omega r^2 C) = 0$$

so the frequency will be
$$ \Longrightarrow  w= \sqrt{\frac{L - r^2 C} {L^2 C}}$$

Comment: Sorry, but the voltage gain is W(s)=-ZF(s)/R.

Comment: @Franc Thank you, it's my typo. Now it's been corrected now.

Comment: Assuming your cubic equation is correct, one solution is w=0. The other solutions should look like the solutions to a quadratic equation. i.e. (-b +/- sqrt(b^2-4ac))/2a. How did you get your final expression?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy It's not \$ \omega (L - \omega^2L^2C - r^2C)\$. It will generate one positive, and one negative results

Comment: @kile What do you mean "It's not \$\omega(L-\omega^2L^2C-r^2C)\$"? That is the same as \$\omega L-\omega^3L^2C-\omega r^2C\$! And \$\omega=0\$ is a root of both of these polynomials.

Comment: not it's a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP (correctly) derived a formula for the resonant frequency of the following LRC circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcQFjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$\omega= \sqrt{\frac{L - r^2 C} {L^2 C}}$$

This formula gives a real answer when the LRC circuit is critically damped or underdamped. (It does not give a real answer when the circuit is overdamped). Thus, it gives a real answer when

$$L \ge r^2 C$$

The following circuit has an LRC feedback subcircuit which satisfies the above criterion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftATDs.png)</sup>

According to the formula above, the resonant frequency of the LRC subcircuit is given by

$$\omega= \sqrt{\frac{L - r^2 C} {L^2 C}} =\sqrt{\frac{10 - (1^2)(1)} {(10^2)(1)}} = \sqrt{\frac{9}{100}} = 0.3 rad/\mu Sec$$

That is 300,000 radians/sec or about 47.7 kHz.

In fact, the Bode plot(s) for this circuit is/are

[image]
[image]

We see that the peak is approximately where we expect it.

---

To evaluate whether this circuit will oscillate, we consider a modification to the circuit per Middlebrook's single injection method (using voltage injection) to determine the loop gain of the circuit. (For those interested, the test signal (Vin) was placed where the forward impedance is high, and the reverse impedance is low. More can be found [here](https://www.edn.com/loop-gain-measurements/).)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn0MPB.png)</sup>

Here are it's Bode diagram(s) for the loop gain.

[image]
[image]

We see that when gain is 0 dB (approximately 2.75 MHz), the phase shift is \$90^{\circ}\$. So this circuit will not oscillate, as it violates the Barkhausen criterion.

Comment: So my algebra calculation is problematic according to your simulation.

Comment: @kile No, they are correct. However, you will get a real answer only if \$L \ge r^2C\$. Also, you circuit does not oscillate. If you want an oscillator, you need a different circuit.

Comment: The feedback system is negative. Because it's connected to the the negative of the op-amp. Am I right? In order to oscillate, positive feedback is needed.

Comment: @kile the feedback is negative because it is connected to the inverting input of the op-amp AND because the feedback loop does not shift the phase enough to make the total phase shift 0 degrees or 360 degrees or ... It is possible to have positive feedback through the inverting input if there is sufficient phase shift in the feedback path. But yours does not.